# SQL: how to group by timestamp column by relative time between dates?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a table with many rows which are records of atomic actions. I wish to group sets of these atomic actions into meta-actions, where the definition of what constitutes a meta-action is when the timestamp is withing 90 days of another row with three specific fields holding the same value (from, to, and subject).

I would like it to group 1-n rows into single meta-actions.

Is this even possible?

```
row | timestamp | from | to | subject | some_data
----------------------------------------------------
1   | 1/1/2018  | A    | B  | RED     | asdfasdf
2   | 1/2/2018  | A    | B  | RED     | asdfasdf
3   | 1/3/2018  | A    | B  | RED     | asdfasdf
4   | 1/5/2018  | C    | D  | BLUE    | asdfasdf
5   | 1/6/2018  | E    | F  | GREEN   | asdfasdf
6   | 1/8/2018  | G    | H  | YELLOW  | asdfasdf
7   | 1/9/2018  | G    | H  | YELLOW  | asdfasdf
8   | 1/6/2019  | G    | H  | YELLOW  | asdfasdf
```

So rows 1,2,3 would output as one record, row 4 as one record, row 5 as one record, rows 6,7 as one record, and row 8 as one record (note 6,7 are 2018, whereas 8 is 2019).

EDIT: I would like the output columns to be the same as the input, but the value of timestamp would be the earliest of the timestamps in any given grouping.

Comment: What do you want in that one record?

Comment: The earliest value of `timestamp`, and then all the other columns. I will add to question, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want as a result set, but this is a literal interpretation of your request:

```
select array_agg(t)
from t
group by from, to, subject, extract(year from timestamp);
```

This produces an array of structs of the values.

If you just want the ids in an array:

```
select from, to, subject, extract(year from timestamp) as year,
       array_agg(id)
from t
group by from, to, subject, extract(year from timestamp);
```

Note:  Keywords such as `from` and `to` are very bad names for columns.  I assume this is only for illustration.  If not, you need to surround them with backticks.

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you. 

Does `year` mean that they are grouped over absolute year ranges, or by 6 months either side? Would `quarter` mean it was 45 days either side? 

(You are correct: I was simplifying for the example, and `some_data` represents several other columns).

Comment: @ChorHataraHud'uKeturi . . . You can refer to the documentation on what `extract()` does, but it returns the calendar year.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(ts ORDER BY day LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] ts, `from`, `to`, `subject`, STRING_AGG(some_data, '; ') all_some_data
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(flag OR (flag IS NULL)) OVER(PARTITION BY `from`,`to`,`subject` ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(day)) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT *, PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', ts) day,
      UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', ts)) - 
      LAG(UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', ts))) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY `from`,`to`,`subject` ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', ts))) > 90 AS flag
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
GROUP BY `from`, `to`, `subject`, grp
```

If to apply to sample data from your question  - result is

```
Row ts          from    to  subject all_some_data    
1   1/1/2018    A       B   RED     asdfasdf1; asdfasdf2; asdfasdf3  
2   1/5/2018    C       D   BLUE    asdfasdf4    
3   1/6/2018    E       F   GREEN   asdfasdf5    
4   1/8/2018    G       H   YELLOW  asdfasdf6; asdfasdf7     
5   1/6/2019    G       H   YELLOW  asdfasdf8
```